# Convert from one dimensional array to 2 dimensional array in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
    #!/bin/bash

    arrNum=(1 2 3 4)

    for ((i = 0; i< 4; i++)) do
        echo -n ${arrNum[i]}
        done
    echo
```

I have an array like this. 1D array. How can I change it to 2D array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What are you trying to do exactly? Show more code. Also what version of bash is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
#!/bin/bash

arrNum=(1 2 3 4)

for ((j = 0; j< 4; j++)) do
    for ((i = 0; i< 4; i++)) do
        echo "${arrNum[i]} - ${arrNum[j]}"
        done
echo
done
```